# SFML program can not load image

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, sfml

I'm trying to develop a game using SFML in Visual Studio:

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "windows.h"

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    sf::VideoMode desktopMode = sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode();
    sf::RenderWindow window(desktopMode, "Ant God Simulator", sf::Style::Fullscreen);

    sf::Texture backgroundTexture;

    if (!backgroundTexture.loadFromFile("C:\\Dev\\AntGodSimulator\\Sprites\\Background-Grass"))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to load background texture.", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return -1;
    }

    sf::Sprite background(backgroundTexture);
    background.setScale(
        (float)desktopMode.width / backgroundTexture.getSize().x,
        (float)desktopMode.height / backgroundTexture.getSize().y
    );

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color(50, 50, 50));
        window.draw(background);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Everything was working fine until I tried to load and display a background image. The program exits immediately, and the background image isn't displayed.

I've tried the following:

- Made sure the path to the image is correct.
- I checked that the image is in the correct directory within the project
- changed image formats (tried both .jpg and .png).
- Ensured that the Debug/Release configurations are set correctly in Visual Studio and that I'm linking to the correct SFML libraries.

Comment: You must pass the extension as a part of the name, I believe.

Comment: `C:\\Dev\\AntGodSimulator\\Sprites\\Background-Grass` is that really the filename with no extension? Maybe your file explorer is set to hide extensions and causing this confusion.

Comment: Sorry I tried adding the extension with the name before and that did not work also it is actually the name of the file ik not great names.

Comment: So was it the `loadFromFile` that failed?  If so, SFML comes with [source code](https://github.com/SFML/SFML).  You could have debugged the code and stepped into the `loadFromFile` function to know exactly why the function returns a failure.

Comment: SFML most certainly can load files. I do it all the time in my own projects.